# OSX application shortcut folder in dock and icon updates after installation

Tags: macos, icons, dock, dmg

Here is the setup: I have the Applications folder right in the dock, which is the default after installation (Snow Leopard) afaik.

Now I have a custom build DMG with an application in there which I drag&drop into the Application folder. When I open the Application folder from the dock and look for the newly installed app, it does not have the application icon it should - it does in fact show the default icon (pencil/paper) with a circle and line through it.

In the Application Folder opened via the Finder shows the Icon after some seconds.

The App is custom build as well. It uses the info.plist to specify the icon file to be used - which is called cc.icns and located in the Contents/Resources folder.

I think this might be a problem with the icon cache and can be resolved by logout/login - a solution that I'm not looking for. Afaik there are apps that do not have this problem. (Right? Wrong?)

Any suggestions on this?

EDIT: This is dupe to https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5161/2123 - but I feel like this forum might have a more technical solution ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circle and line through your app icon is usual with new applications, at least until you run it the first time and confirm that you want to run it.

Applications that have installers already get the confirmation so that they don't have to go through the extra step.

If you codesign your application, then after the first time you run it and confirm that you want it to run, subsequent installations of the application on that machine do not need to be approved, as long as the signature is the same.